# Why won't my UITableViewCells show information?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I start my app it should show the name and location data of all the parties in my database but it doesn't. I'm pretty sure I'm getting the right data but i don't know whats wrong. How do I get my table to show all the data and update each time new data is added?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class FindPartiesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    var parties = [party]()

    @IBOutlet weak var partyTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        partyTable.delegate = self
        partyTable.dataSource = self

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        ref.child("parties").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
            snapshot in
            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let name = snapshotValue?["name"] as! String
            let location = snapshotValue?["location"] as! String
            let description = snapshotValue?["description"] as! String

            self.parties.append(party(name: name, description: description, location: location))
        })

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // creates the number of cells in the table
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return parties.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Make table cells the show the user name
        var cell = partyTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

        let nameLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        nameLabel.text = parties[indexPath.row].name

        let locationLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        locationLabel.text = parties[indexPath.row].location


        return cell!
    }

}
```

Here is my database setup:

```
testApp
      parties
           -KUUzxkssjWoSZ22QS8r
                description: ""
                location: "Here"
                name: "party 1"
          -KUV0ObFVbPyI_SJ0f3F
                description: ""      
                location: "There"
                name: "party 2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reload the table view after updating your data model:

```
ref.child("parties").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
    snapshot in
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    let name = snapshotValue?["name"] as! String
    let location = snapshotValue?["location"] as! String
    let description = snapshotValue?["description"] as! String

    self.parties.append(party(name: name, description: description, location: location))

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        partyTable.reloadData()
    }
})
```